# Who stole the darkness from the accepted-answer-tick?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, design

At first I thought my eyes were fooling me, but after taking a second look, I found the SO answer-tick to be brighter than before!

old:
[image: Old accepted-answer checkmark]
new:
[image: New accepted-answer checkmark]

(I find the new color to be too bright and stingy, especially with the white background. The old darker green was nicer for the eyes. Can haz old color back?)

Comment: I don't like it, change it.

Comment: I like it. Change it anyway.

Comment: I don't like the new color. I hurts my eyes, and it's MSPainty.

Comment: I like it. A checkmark should have a recognizable green.

Comment: CHANGE HAPPENED. CHANGE BAD. HULK SMASH

Comment: [In a good way](https://twitter.com/minitechme/status/348148182879977472)

Comment: If I hadn't seen this post, I would never have noticed the change.

Comment: I've seen this post, and I still don't recognise any change. Thanks to low brightness settings :D

Comment: Low brightness settings here and it still hurts my eyes.

Comment: Bright pixels! OMG the ponies will be mad! The power, it wastes away!

Comment: Neat, they even remembered to update the [guided tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) with the new color! :-)

Comment: It's bright for me on SO but darker here on meta. hmm.

Comment: Andrew likes green.

Comment: We should all stop accepting answers in protest.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I say we should unaccept old answers to remove the vile color from our screens.

Comment: I updated some of the Trilogy sites icons yesterday. It started with the small green checkmarks on the /badges page first. The old one was way too big and made the page looking busy if you have a lot of badges earned. The new version is smaller and less obtrusive. I made the smaller checkmark slightly brighter because the old green looked almost gray-ish at that size. This lead me to update the accepted answer checkmark to match its color to be consistent. TL;DR: I stole the darkness, but I think you'll get used to it in no time.

Comment: I actually thought I changed some settings on my monitor without knowing it. I do like the old color better as it's less obtrusive.

Comment: This is a feature request that has been declined. If you support this feature, please open a new discussion with new reasons that it should be considered.

Comment: @TimPost If this is a feature request, then it isn't off-topic after all.

Comment: On second thought, I'm just leaving this reopened.

Comment: @Jin: Hey, why is that not an answer? :)

Comment: @Jin, So more than 3/4 of the users want the old green color back and you reply saying that we will get used in no time? Stupid me that I thought this was a democratic community.

Comment: I like the new color. It's bright, optimistic, grateful... Wait, I'm going to ask people to accept answers so I see it more often....

Comment: @Jeffrey: Or maybe only 48 users out of almost two million noticed and decided it was bad.

Comment: @minitechη No, 49. But I'll stop complaining and hope my eyes get used to it…

Comment: I agree that looks terrible, but... I'm pretty sure it's the artifacts caused by your very low-quality JPEG compression. Next time use PNG...

Comment: Call me No.50 - it hurts to look at it, and actually has less presence on the page compared to the darker version.

Comment: Change it to magenta, please.

Comment: @minitech Infrared would be better.

Comment: I'm curious how 80 some odd votes equates to 2/3 of all users on [so], given that there are roughly 2 million active users of that site daily, if not 5 million (not registered, just active) and so far 80 have bothered to register a vote on the matter of "restoring" based on the above question. So, that's just about .00004% of active users which is to say less than $4 of my income for the year. I'll spend more than that on any given lunch this week, which I won't care about at the end of the year. So, you're not exactly measuring a sufficient subset of the data to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 30):

I just counted, and the check mark is all of 30px wide. I don't care if it's high visibility yellow or safety orange, nothing that small short of a 5W LED is going to hurt your eyes.

Yes, it's noticeably different if you're used to the darker icon. A week or two from now you'll be used to the new one and you won't notice it anymore -- unless you get so worked up about the issue that it becomes a pet peeve which eats into your soul and gives you fits every time you see an accepted answer. **Solution:** relax, don't get worked up about it.

**Also:** If you do happen to get worked up about it, this kind of thing is often pretty easy to adjust yourself with a browser plug-in. Tools like Greasemonkey and Stylish make web sites customizable.

Comment: Who says I'm not relaxed? :)

Comment: @Xeo I certainly don't. Was responding more to the 'hurts my eyes' comment above, but I don't mean to attribute that to you. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: On a side note, the drawing area of the sprite seems to be 30x31 pixels to be more precise.

Comment: +1 - I like this answer. Although given the topicality it may never see the overbearing BRIGHT green check mark.

Comment: Solution: don't write good answers and don't accept answers to questions. Simple.

Comment: I still cry at night.

Answer (score 15):

Praise! For I have fixed our problems forever (well, hopefully).

I have created a user script, which embeds the old image (instead of relying upon an outside server which probably *will* change over time), and now we finally have our victory!

Here's a screenshot in-action:

[image]

## [Download Me Now!](https://stackapps.com/questions/4170/sooldcheckmark-bring-back-the-old-checkmark)

Comment: @icktoofay I know that, there was another answer which did rely upon the outside server. This provides a solution for FireFox & Safari users, instead of just chrome.

Comment: The script is breaking a whole lot of JavaScript on the SE network, because it requires jQuery 2.0 while SE runs on 1.7.1

Comment: @Stijn good to know, I'm working on a fix.

Answer (score 7):

## Chrome Extension

I found an old `sprites.png` file [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png) and packaged it up along with a small CSS file into a small Chrome extension. I'm pretty sure this is the wrong way to distribute it but I have made the CRX file available [here](http://usertracker.org/luminance-overflow/lumoverflow.crx). Unzip the CRX for the source.

Comment: You could probably make it a greasemonkey script by base64'ing the file. Working on that now

Answer (score 7):

> Can haz old color back?

Yes we can!

---

### Method 1: using the old “sprites.png”

Using the sprites [icktoofay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/210346/icktoofay) found, minimalistically you just need to add the following rule in your user CSS to get the darker green check-mark.

```
.vote .vote-accepted-on {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png');
}
```

---

### Method 2: base64 image data of old checkmark embedded in CSS

Adapting Richard's excellent [base64 solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185459/225020) to use the image of a single (gorgeous, low-contrast, dark green) checkmark instead of using the entire sprite, this is the resulting CSS rule.

```
.vote .vote-accepted-on {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: 0% 0%; 
}
```

---

### Appendix C: Applying user/custom CSS

1. Browser's built-in method (e.g. Opera's way to using user css is documented [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/usercss/)).
2. Greasemonkey script (see [Richard's solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185459/225020))
3. Stylish plugin (available on [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), and possibly [Safari](https://github.com/350d/stylish))

Note: Applying CSS by domains is easy for #2 and #3, I'm not sure about #1.