# This shouldn't have been put on-hold

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I recently stumbled across [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185401/who-stole-the-darkness-from-the-accepted-answer-tick-on-hold).

It's about the change in the color of the accept tick mark on Stack Overflow - an honorable thing to complain about. I don't like it either. However, the question (which amounts to: *can we change the tick mark back?*) was just closed as 'primarily opinion based'.

Really? The guy is asking *whether or not SE will bring back the old color*. That's not primarily opinion based, unless it's Joel's opinion.

I'm assuming it was closed as such because some people like the color. If that's the case, then *every other feature-request on all of Meta* should be closed.

Heck, my [77-scoring feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit) should be. Some people didn't like it.

Seriously, guys?

> **Note:** This is not about this one instance. It's about the future of Meta and closing. If this can happen to any feature request, we have a problem.

Comment: Vote to re-open / flag. Edit it to make it clear how it's not "primarily opinion based". Let's not make a habit of posting a Meta question about a single closure (on-holdure?), at least until we've exhausted every other option.

Comment: @Yannis I understand that, but figured this is a *serious problem* for the use of the new system on Meta. I've flagged (getting closer to 3k :).

Comment: A question getting incorrectly closed (on-holded?) is not a _serious problem_.

Comment: @Yannis This early in the introduction of a new system, it is. I'm okay with disagreeing if you want to.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with the new closing system at all. Probably wouldn't have been closed if it was marked as a feature request rather than a discussion.

Comment: Cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191773/vote-to-close-as-primarily-opinion-based-on-meta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had originally reopened it, tagged it as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and marked it [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). I then closed it as Off Topic -> Custom with the [following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185401/who-stole-the-darkness-from-the-accepted-answer-tick?noredirect=1&noredirect=1&noredirect=1&noredirect=1#comment567954_185401):

> This is a feature request that has been declined. If you support this feature, please open a new discussion with new reasons that it should be considered.

Common sense then kicked in and told me ... it really *was* a feature request, and didn't need to be closed. It's now reopened.

I think this points out that we have to be careful to not look at the work flow of close reasons until we're certain that the post needed to be closed in the first place - something I just initially failed to do.

Comment: "Common sense then kicked in and told me" Oh, I remember that feeling, it was nasty. Took me years of tequila therapy to get over it.

Answer (score 5):

Meh. Firstly, it's tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and I think that's what sparked this.

The closing basically meant:

> You want us to *discuss* the differences between two shades of green? Really?

I guess "primarily opinion based" isn't the best wording here, the closevoters must have closed it keeping in mind the older wording of NC -- "not constructive". It really isn't constructive on meta. As a feature-request, maybe, but not as a discussion.

Comment: Yes, NC would have been better

Comment: *shakes head at new close reasons*