# How did a normal user vote to reopen a post after a mod?

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, vote-to-reopen

> **Post Reopened** by Tim Post ♦, waiwai933

On [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/185401/revisions), right above Rev. 3.

How did that happen? How did a normal user vote to reopen *after* Tim cast a binding reopen vote?

Note that this happened 22 hours ago as of the time of this post, and Tim was and is a member of the community team with full moderator privileges.

Comment: I don't know, but that post's been in a bit of a rollback war between TimPost and himself. Maybe TimPost made a sock pupet account to show TimPost that he had the support of the community. (I mean, seriously? Reopen, close, reopen, close, ...)

Comment: @Linuxios I can explain that part. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185428/215468

Comment: It's considerably less obvious when there's no moderator involved, but it does appear that re-open voters are being consistently displayed in reverse chronological order. [Here's another example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/185402/revisions)

Comment: Yep, it's a bug.  .sdrawkcab si gnihtyrevE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were not recording the reopen votes in the correct order in the post history.

This has been fixed and going forward (starting with the next build) they will be ordered by creation time.

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure why it's displayed in the order that it is, but I actually cast the *second* re-open vote on that question, so what you're seeing is in fact an artifact of the re-openers not being displayed in the order that they voted.

I'm not entirely sure if that's by design, however there's no sort of privilege escalation at play here.

**Update**

This does appear to be a bug. Everything is backwards and we're all ***doomed***, the world is being rewound as if it were a VHS cassette.

Comment: I prefer to rewind my DVDs too.

Comment: @ColeJohnson What about us people using singly-linked lists and riding dinosaurs?