# Why am I shown as the first person to reopen a question, when in fact I'm the last?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen, reopened-questions

This is rather weird, and maybe I'm missing something (I almost hope I am, because then this question should be closed as too localized ;P).

I saw this question in the reopen queue and voted to reopen it, however, I noticed in the revision history that it places me as the *first* person to vote on the question, when in fact I had just cast the *last* vote.

[image]
[image]

Comment: ... Because it's upside-down? - I'd assume it just picks them out of the database in reverse order so it doesn't take ages to load for a recent post.

Comment: @FEichinger What's upside down?

Comment: The list of reviewers. Begins with the most recent, ends with the first. - The same goes for the voter list, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Well that's not the way it used to be...

Comment: There's a bug with the reopen notices where it's been listing the participants in reverse order. [Related question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185512/how-did-a-normal-user-vote-to-reopen-a-post-after-a-mod)

Comment: @animuson >.< I love funny titles but sometimes it makes it hard to find dupes.

Comment: Apparently reopen votes are LIFO

Comment: @Mike But is it *supposed* to be that way? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters does it? If the list were presented in FIFO would anything really change? if it is a bug, it's very minor IMO

Comment: @Mike I dunno. It would just be weird to have it LIFO.

Comment: @Seth: Both the SE staff in the linked question say it's a bug.