# Accepted answer colour inconsistency

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, design

Why does the accepted answer use 3 different colours? It feels inconsistent across the site.

[image]

On the main answer page the accepted answer colour is a bright green (#46b525)

Where as the accepted answer colour that displays on my profile summary is darker: #75845c

And the accepted answer in the reputation summary is again different: #008000

Not so much a bug or a problem but just wondered the reason for this.

Comment: The whole thing is going through some changes atm: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185401/who-stole-the-darkness-from-the-accepted-answer-tick